# Multi Processing in Azure Data Bricks - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, azure-databricks

I need to run multiple notebooks in Azure Data Bricks parallelly, but getting error when trying to run below code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
  p1 = executor.submit(dbutils.notebook.run,'/Notebook1',0)
  p2 = executor.submit(dbutils.notebook.run,'/Notebook2',0)
  
print(p1.result(),p2.result())
```

Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

However, I am able to successfully implement using multithreading:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
  p1 = executor.submit(dbutils.notebook.run,'/Notebook1',0)
  p2 = executor.submit(dbutils.notebook.run,'/Notebook2',0)
  
print(p1.result(),p2.result())
```

But need to leevrage multiprocessing, any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks
Kaushal

Comment: why do you need multiprocessing? Thread pool is enough for your task

Comment: I am new to parallel processing, but as far as I have read, multi processing enables you to utilize more cores/processors which is not the case in multithreading(divides existing processor within different threads). Cluster I am working on has good number of cores, which I am unable to utilize parallelly.

Comment: that's not really correct - in process you have fully isolated environment that doesn't inherit settings, etc. But for your task, the main job of thread is to submit notebook for execution and wait for it executed - the execution itself will be submitted to the whole cluster

Comment: Ohk. That's great then, it works for me. Thanks.
Still out of curiosity I'd want to understand why I am unable to implement multi processing in ADB, and how can I do it?

Comment: when you start a new process, the SparkSession will be "empty", but it's used by the notebooks that you're executing - that's why you're getting this specific error. When you use threads, they all are sharing the same SparkSession

Comment: Thaks for the help :)